# How to get a map for a lookup table in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, unique, indices

I have two different datasets with categorical data and two corresponding keys for each dataset.

So imagine dataset1 with values `[0,1,1,0,2]`
with keys that represent the categoryKey:`['cat','dog','mouse']`

and dataset2 with values `[0,1,2,2,1,2]`
with categoryKey:`['dog','mouse','cat']`

I would want to transform dataset2 to match dataset1, by finding the proper key mapping. In this case, the map for dataset 2 to match the keys to dataset 1 is `[1,2,0]`. Applied as a lookup for dataset2, it would transform it thus: `[0,1,2,2,1,2]->[1,2,0,0,2,0]`

and then dataset1 and 2 would have the correct categories w.r.t. each other.

This is pretty straightforward with a list comprehension in normal python, but instead, I am working with tensorflow, so imagine dataset1 and dataset2 are tensors of shape `[100,100]`. What tensorflow operation can I do to produce a map `[1,2,0]`?

In truth, datasets 1 and 2 are batches of data, as well as `categorieKeys` are also batches with shapes of >(3,3). So we cannot convert from tensors to numpy then to lists and do list comprehension.

What is the correct tensorflow operation to find the map, and then to transform the data?